# SignalR core hubconnection lambda action

Tags: c#, lambda, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a simple SignalR core hub connection and the hub connection has an `On` method which takes an action handler I currently have it with a lambda like following but I want to use a event handler so I can unsubscribe it easily and prevent any memory leaks.

```
hubConnection.On<string, string>(ReceiveMethodKey, (user, message) =>
            {
                var finalMessage = $"{user} says {message}";
                // Update the UI
            });
```

Comment: Why not pass a `delegate`?  You can null that out, just like an event.

Comment: can you show me an example? @Zer0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a delegate:

```
class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    private Action<string, string> HubConnectionOnDelegate;

    private void InitOrSomething()
    {
        //Pointer to a method, anonymous method, whatever...
        HubConnectionOnDelegate = HubConnection_On;
    }

    private static void HubConnection_On(string user, string message)
    {
        var finalMessage = $"{user} says {message}";
        // Update the UI
    }

    private void Elsewhere()
    {
        hubConnection.On<string, string>(ReceiveMethodKey, HubConnectionOnDelegate);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        HubConnectionOnDelegate = null;
    }
}
```